# What is better way to estimate marginal density?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Let there be the random variables $X$ and $Y$. We have a sample of $X$'s and Y's together. To most accurately estimate the density $f_X$, would we...

1) Ignore the Y's and estimate $f_X$ only from the $X$'s

2) Estimate $f_{X, Y}$ and then find the marginal $f_X$ by integrating $f_{X, Y}$ (let us assume here that numeric integration is both fast and precise)

I suppose the crux of the question is this: Do we learn more about the marginal distribution of $X$ from observing samples of $X$ and $Y$ versus $X$ alone?

Comment: Are you familiar the copula concept?

Comment: I have briefly heard of it, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think analytically both approaches are equivalent: *all information you can gain from $X$ lies within its probability distribution $f_X$*. Using $Y$ as well as $X$ only is convenient if you are interested in the combined probability distribution $f_{X,Y}$.
If we are talking about numerical efficiency, it seems estimating $f_X$ from $X$ avoids computations and thus is faster and more accurate (however, the actual difference might be negligible).